# Get full domain URL with expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to get the full URL using expressjs but it doesn't work with my code, I get the IP Adress and not the domain name...

My code : `request.protocol + '://' + request.get('host') + request.originalUrl`

Result : `http://127.0.0.1:3009/`

Should be : `http://domainaname.fr/blog/1/name-of-my-article`

**Edit #1**

```js
{ host: '127.0.0.1:3009',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   via: '1.1 SRVAFW32K3',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   cookie: '__utma=118302353.915172217.1415970012.1418720938.1418727366.17; __utmc=118302353; __utmz=118302353.1417190225.6.3.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); _ga=****; connect.sid=s%3Ashyx4InRi3AR89XyuSkHxDwXFXW3BbTF.**%2FQMG8fQqqPdc',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   'if-none-match': 'W/"1d58-1752282781"',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6,de;q=0.4,es;q=0.2,fil;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,pt;q=0.2',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   'x-forwarded-for': '90.*.*.71',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   'x-forwarded-host': 'mydomain',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   'x-forwarded-server': 'mydomain.fr',
[mydomain.fr.3009-27 (out)]   connection: 'Keep-Alive' }
```

Comment: What version of express are you using? Are you sure you don't request exactly that ip and port returned in the result? (looks like testing an app on localhost).

Comment: i'm using Express 4.8.7 and I'm not testing my app on localhost...

Comment: Are you using some local reverse proxy? Try `console.log(req.headers)` to see detailed information about the headers.

Comment: Okay, probably a bit more information for the public than desired? ... ;). So, when I request [this URL](http://demo-gestiawebcms.icecom.fr/blog/1/Bienvenue-sur-notre-nouveau-site-internet) - what I actually just did: What does your node log tell you?

Comment: See edit#1, this is what the log tell me..